# How to use divide function in sql command?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a sql command in vb.net application and I'm trying to divide two columns.

I tried using simple div command but I get an error every time I run the application.

```
           SELECT ISNULL(r.GameStart,0) as GameStart,
           ISNULL(r.ElecCoinIn,0) as ElecCoinIn,
   (ISNULL(r.GameStart,0) / ISNULL(r.ElecCoinIn,0) as AverageBet,
   ISNULL(sm.OnFloor,0) as OnFloor, 
   ISNULL(sm.OffFloor,0) as OffFloor,
   ISNULL(sm.Description,0) as Description,
   ISNULL(sm.LocationString,0) as LocationString, agg.*
   FROM dbo.CDS_SLOTMAST sm (NOLOCK) 
    INNER JOIN dbo.BB_REVENUE r (NOLOCK) 
  ON sm.SlotMast_ID=r.SlotMast_ID 
  INNER JOIN agg ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), r.AuditDate, 120) = agg.[Date]
  ORDER BY r.AuditDate
```

This is just one part of my code

The error I get iS: Incorrect syntax near "ISNULL" .
I have never worked with SQL operators before, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What database are you using?  Why not just use `/`?

Comment: I just edit my code, this is what I have tried and I always get the same error. I'm using MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't checked for NULLS on your divide.

```
SELECT ISNULL(r.GameStart,0) as GameStart,
       ISNULL(r.ElecCoinIn,0) as ElecCoinIn,
  CASE WHEN ISNULL( r.ElecCoinIn,0) <> 0 THEN ( ISNULL(r.GameStart,0) / r.ElecCoinIn) ELSE 0 END as AverageBet,
   ISNULL(sm.OnFloor,0) as OnFloor, 
   ISNULL(sm.OffFloor,0) as OffFloor,
   ISNULL(sm.Description,0) as Description,
   ISNULL(sm.LocationString,0) as LocationString, agg.*
   FROM dbo.CDS_SLOTMAST sm (NOLOCK) 
    INNER JOIN dbo.BB_REVENUE r (NOLOCK) 
  ON sm.SlotMast_ID=r.SlotMast_ID 
  INNER JOIN agg ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), r.AuditDate, 120) = agg.[Date]
  ORDER BY r.AuditDate
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent a divide-by-zero error, use `nullif()`:

```
ISNULL(r.GameStart, 0) / NULLIF(r.ElecCoinIn, 0) as AverageBet,
```

This returns `NULL` instead of a division error.

Comment: This is not only safe, but also succinct and idiomatic. It's far better than the currently accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a right parenthesis in:

```
(ISNULL(r.GameStart,0) / ISNULL(r.ElecCoinIn,0) as AverageBet,
```